# Map each element in a Series to a Series and combine the result into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

For example, suppose there is a series

```
0     'pikachu'
1     'squirtle'
```

and a mapping that map pokemon name to the series consisting of its color and weight.

For instance, 'pikachu' maps to the series

```
color    'yellow'
weight   5
```

I wonder how I could get a DataFrame that looks like

```
    pokemon    color       weight
0   pikachu    'yellow'    5
1   squirtle   'blue'      8
```

The current solution I can come up with comprised of many `pd.concat`, but I suspect there might be a cleaner way.

Comment: What does the mapping look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store them as dictionary:

```
In [11]: pika
Out[11]: 
color     yellow
weight         5
dtype: object

In [12]: squi
Out[12]: 
color     blue
weight       8
dtype: object

In [13]: pokes = {'pikachu': pika, 'squirtle': squi}
```

Then you can use the get method (takes name and returns Series):

```
In [14]: pokemon
Out[14]: 
0     pikachu
1    squirtle
dtype: object

In [15]: pokemon.apply(pokes.get)
Out[15]: 
    color  weight
0  yellow       5
1    blue       8
```

*Note: add the column of names using `_['name'] = pokemon`.*

Or you can use the from_dict method:

```
In [21]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pokes, orient='index')
Out[21]: 
           color  weight
pikachu   yellow       5
squirtle    blue       8
```